# Swipe carousel responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css, swipe

I'm using **Swipe** carousel, I need it to make responsive (decrease image height and width while resizing browser), but not sure why, the `.swiper-slide` width remaining larger, though it's width is auto. Did anybody meet such problem? Also after browser maximize, image widths are not updated. See in screenshots.

[image]

[image]

***HTML***

```
<div class="block-carousel">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img1.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img2.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img1.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img1.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img1.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img1.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img2.jpg') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <?= HTML::image('/assets/images/tmp/carousel/img1.jpg') ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination">
      <div class="swiper-prev">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-next">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    nextButton: '.swiper-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-prev',
    paginationClickable: true
  });

  var imgHeight = $(window).width()/2;
  $('.swiper-slide').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).children('img').width();
    $(this).css('width', width + 'px');
  });

  $('.block-carousel').css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  var imgHeight = $(window).width()/2;

  $('.swiper-slide').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).children('img').width();
    $(this).css('width', width + 'px');
  });

  $('.block-carousel').css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
});
```

***CSS***

```
.swiper-container .swiper-slide {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 0!important;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.swiper-container .swiper-slide img {
  width: auto;
}
.swiper-container .swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.swiper-wrapper * {
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-container {
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination {
  bottom: auto;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.swiper-prev,
.swiper-next {
  width: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  line-height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.swiper-prev {
  margin-left: 45px;
  float: left;
}
.swiper-next {
  margin-right: 45px;
  float: right;
}
```

Code is in fiddle, but for some reasons it's not working.

***Note:*** I just want to make the carousel responsive (resize images height/width during browser resize)

Comment: Can't see a fiddle attached to your question.